# Extract local time and timezone offset information using date-fns

Tags: javascript, date-fns

I have the following `date` string: `2022-04-16T18:31:00+02:00` and I would like to extract the local time i.e. `2022-04-16T18:31` and offset information `+2:00` or `2` using `date-fns`.

I know I can do it with a simple string manipulation like this:

```js
const [dateTime, offset] = "2022-04-16T18:31:00+02:00".split('+')
```

However, if possible, I would like to avoid string manipulation and use the library instead.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should look from [date-fns-tz](https://github.com/marnusw/date-fns-tz).

Check the method (utcToZonedTime, getTimezoneOffset).

Hope this help

Answer (score 0):

I can see not many people is answering here so, here is how you can get date and time in Javascript with this kind of string

``````
const [dateTime, offset] = "2022-04-16T18:31:00+02:00".split('+');

var newDate = dateTime;

//above variable newDate will hold value that is => 2022-04-16T18:31:00

//don't use split('+'); so you can get Timezone as well 



getTimeZone =  "2022-04-16T18:31:0002:00";
var getTimeZone = getTimeZone.substring(19, getTimeZone.length-0);


console.log("timezone is "+ getTimeZone);

`````
``````

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this... *[untested code]*

```
import { format } from "date-fns";

const d = Date.parse("2022-04-16T18:31:00+02:00");
const outputDate = `${format(d, "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm")}`;

console.log(outputDate);
```